# How to exclude $PROJECT_ROOT/.idea from watched files in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, watch, rubymine

I am using RubyMine as my editor for a Jekyll project. RubyMine uses a control directory named `.idea`, and a file there, `workspace.xml` is constantly changing. My problem is that this causes many, many unnecessary builds. Is there any way to exclude this directory from that which the watcher is watching?

There are a couple of similar questions on StackOverflow, but they involve using the `exclude` configuration variable to exclude a directory within the source document directory (usually `_posts`, right?), and exclude them from conversion, not from watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exclude:
  - .idea
```

Will avoid ***.idea*** folder to be watched. Note, that it will also override [default exclude](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/site_template/_config.yml#L33)